# "&" Symbol in String of my class is not considered as a part of it

Tags: android, string, web-services, url

I have a `String s="&0_o10&";`

I am using this string in a webservice call as url. This string is a part of the url.I have dubugged the code , but its taking the string as `"0_o10"`  **instead of**  `"&0_o10&"`.

Please help me .

Comment: Are you using POST method for calling webservice?

Comment: you can use %26 instend of &. OR use encode method of URLEncoder.

Comment: I am using GET method @Prince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with URLs, if they contain anything that isn't a letter or a number, they should be encoded prior to using them.

Use:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode("&0_o10&", "UTF-8");
```

should result in something like `%260_o10%26` that can be used with the webservice